# После сборки и отправки на сервер не видит пакет через @

Tags: node.js, google-maps

Я установил библиотеку [@google/maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/maps).

```
import maps from '@google/maps';

const googleMapsClient = maps.createClient({
    key: 'key',
    rate: { limit: 50 },
    Promise: Promise
});


googleMapsClient.geocode({ address: req.body.merchant_address })
    .asPromise()
    .then((res) => {
        location = res.json.results[0].geometry.location;
        console.log('0 ' + location);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        return res.status(500).json({
        err: err
    });
});
console.log('1 ' + location)
```

При сборки проекта, команда `babel src --out-dir backend` в файле `package.json`, при запуске на сервере выдает ошибку `Error: Cannot find module '@google/maps'`, почему он не видит `'@google/maps'`?

<strike>ПОБОЧНАЯ ПРОБЛЕМА: у меня не получается сделать `googleMapsClient` синхронным. То есть чтобы сперва сработала коменда `console.log('0 ' + ...);` а за ней `console.log('1 ' + ...);`</strike>

Comment: Очевидно, у Вас проблемы с импортом: вы используете переменную `maps`, но откуда уверенность, что библиотека экспортирует ее по дефолту? По поводу синхронности, Вам нужно использовать другую конструкцию, что-то вроде этого: `const res = await googleMapsClient.geocode({ address: req.body.merchant_address });`

Comment: @Doigrales с синхроностью разобрался, а вот с библиотекой не могу, после сборки все выдает ошибку. Как можно поступить?

Comment: Используйте `require('@google/maps')`, посмотрите в консоли результат, по результату будет ясно, применим ли импорт ES6.

Comment: @Doigrales, попробовилвсе равно ошибка на сервере `Error: Cannot find module '@google/maps'`. Все остальные импорты работают хорошо, кроме этого

Comment: Смотрите наличие папки `@google/maps` в `node_modules`, если её там нет, то пробуете еще раз `npm install @google/maps`. Если и это не помогает, то пробуйте обновить npm `npm install -g npm` и повторить действия выше.

Comment: Папки в `@google/maps` в `node_modules` есть. Много раз пробовал установаить заново `install @google/maps`, обновлять тоже пробовал. Все импорты видит, кроме этого, уже который день не могу понять почему

Comment: Проверил у себя, установил и сделал импорт `import * as maps from '@google/maps'` и все работает, что у вас за проблема не ясно, но по крайней мере `require('@google/maps')` должно работать

Comment: Я попробовал локально, сделал импорт `import * as maps from '@google/maps'`, запишил на `heroku` при запуске сервера выдает ошибку в консоле `Error: Cannot find module '@google/maps'`. Може это с `heroku` что то?